# When does IEnumerable.GetEnumerator get called instead of IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, ienumerator

Looking at this code :

```
public class myWords : IEnumerable<string>
{
    string[] f = "I love you".Split(new string[]{"lo"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return f.Select(s => s + "2").GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return f.Select(s => s + "3").GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Running :

```
 myWords m = new myWords();
 foreach (var s in m)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(s);
 }
```

Yields

```
I 2
ve you2    // notice "2", so the generic Ienumerator has executed.
```

I   understand that the  non-generic `IEnumerator` version is for  compatibility.

**Question:**

1. In what scenario will the non-generic be invoked?
2. How can I *force* my code to be run with the non-generic `IEnumerator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers sort of miss the point.

Interfaces do not matter at all if the (compile-time) type of what is beeing `foreach`ed has a `public` non-generic non-static method called `GetEnumerator` which takes zero arguments. (The return type of this method can be anything, generic or non-generic: interfaces will not matter.)

So the reason why the first of your methods is called, is that this is the `public` method.

You can change that:

```
public class myWords : IEnumerable<string>
{
    string[] f = "I love you".Split(new string[]{"lo"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return f.Select(s => s + "2").GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return f.Select(s => s + "3").GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

To prove that interfaces are not needed, try this:

```
public class myWords // no interfaces!
{
    string[] f = "I love you".Split(new string[]{"lo"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return f.Select(s => s + "3").GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

However, it is wise to implement `IEnumerable<>`. Then your type can be used with Linq (extension methods on `IEnumerable<>`), and can be used as argument to other methods that simply require an `IEnumerable<>`.

Also, it is wise to have the method (or explicit interface implementation) that returns the non-generic `IEnumerator` just call through to the method (or explicit interface implementation) that returns `IEnumerator<>`. Having the two return distinct sequences is really confusing (but nice for asking and answering questions on how things work).

Comment: If you're trying to show that interfaces aren't needed, I'd suggest implementing a structure which has a `Current` property and `MoveNext` method but doesn't implement any interfaces, and have `myWords`' `GetEnumerator` method return that type rather than `IEnumerable`.

Comment: OK, "rather than `IEnumerator`" you mean, I guess. What I was trying to say, was the C# compiler will go for the `public` method on the conditions I specified, so whether there are interfaces, and what the interfaces map to, will not matter. I was not saying that the `foreach` would proceed as intended/expected. I am about to try your suggestion.

Comment: @supercat What I wrote worked. This: `class DoMe
    {
        public BadE GetEnumerator()
        {
            return default(BadE);
        }
    }
    struct BadE
    {
        ushort state;

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            ++state;
            return true;
        }

        public string Current
        {
            get
            {
                return arr[state % 4];
            }
        }

        static readonly string[] arr = { "a", "b", "c", "d", };
    }` Creating a new `DoMe` and `foreach`ing it works. What have I shown?

Comment: Formatting in a comment is ugly, but that looks like what I had in mind.  In your answer, type `myWords` has a `GetEnumerator` method that returns `IEnumerator`; I think it's helpful to show that not only does the thing with the `GetEnumerator` method not have to implement an interface, but the enumerator itself doesn't have to implement an interface either.

Comment: @supercat OK, I see your point. Note that if you have `public void GetEnumerator() { }`, and additionally implement `IEnumerable<>` explicitly, the C# compiler will still go for the public method. The return type `void` is not suitable, so it gives a compile-time error. But it still uses the public method and disregard any interfaces the type implements.

Answer (score 7):

The non-generic IEnumerator will be executed whenever code casts the class to the non-generic interface:

```
((IEnumerable)myWords).GetEnumerator(); // this calls the non-generic one
```

This is mostly relevant if you pass your class to some legacy function that requires a non-generic IEnumerator.

So if you have some library that contains a function and you pass your class to this function, it will use the non-generic IEnumerator

```
DoSomeStuffWithAnIEnumerable(IEnumerable x)
{
   var foo = x.GetEnumerator();

   // or, as stackx said, an example with foreach:
   foreach (var foo2 in x)
   Console.WriteLine(foo2);
}


DoSomeStuffWithAnIEnumerable(new myWords());
```

Note that it is perfectly valid to simply implement the non-generic IEnumerator using the generic one:

```
public class myWords : IEnumerable<string>
{
    ....    
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

That way you can be sure that they both have the same effects.

Comment: Or, to give an example using `foreach`: `foreach (object word in (IEnumerable)myWords) …`

Answer (score 4):

The non-generic version of the `IEnumerable` is implemented with an explicit interface implementation. This means that you can only call the explicitly implemented function by casting to the interface.

The reason `IEnumerable` is implemented explicitly is that the method signatures are the same except for the return type.

Casting `myWords` explicitly to `IEnumerable` allows you to call the non-generic version like this: `(IEnumerable)myWords`.

The C# Guide explains how this works: [Explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx).